# What surface is created by a continuous rotation in n-dimension?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Given a random rotation in n-dimensions, what surface is created?

In 2 dimensions this is obviously the circle. The same is true in 3 dimensions. (Any continuous rotation in 3 dimensions of a random point around the origin will produce a circle or a degenerate point if the rotation axis is through the point).

But in 4-dimensions once could have rotation which is a combination of a rotation in the $xy$ axis combined with a rotation in the $zw$ axis, and if these rotations are not rational ratios of each other, a point a 4D space will never return to its starting point. So this can't be a circle. (What shape is it? A torus? Will it go through all points in space?)

Similarly what shapes are produced in n-dimensions by a continuous n-dimensional rotation of a point around the origin? Is there a general theory behind this?

Comment: What object are you rotating?  A point?

Comment: @Matt Hmm, OK I'll use that definition of orthogonal transformation. I mean it just depends on your definition of what a "rotation" is in 4 dimensions.

Comment: @Randall. Yes an arbitrary point (not the origin).